# Html span element does not get hidden

Tags: html, css

In the following code the html span element does not get hidden in-spite of setting the position property to absolute and overflow property to hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body data-rsssl=1>
    <div style="height:20px; width:30px; position:absolute">
      <span style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; white-space: nowrap; display:block; top:0px;left:0px;width:100px;height:30px">
 span element
</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/o0h8fmkg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `overflow` on the parent that's trimming the element, not on the element that's being trimmed:

```css
div {
  height:20px; 
  width:30px; 
  position:absolute; 
  overflow:hidden;
  /** let's see it **/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
  position:absolute; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display:block; 
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body data-rsssl=1>
    <div>
      <span>span element</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had the same doubt. But the mozilla MDN docs example sets it on the element that is being trimmed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow. Use the developer tools to see the property set on the <p> element. I can't find any reliable source that explicitly states this rule.

Comment: That is because in that example the content requires more `height` than the set `height` on the element and what ***is actually being trimmed*** is the contents of the element itself, which requires more `height`. But in your example you gave the span `width: 100px` which accommodated its entire contents. Had you given it more content, it would have been trimmed at the provided `100px` of `width`.

Comment: Is the right solution is to wrap the <p> element within another div that has 100% width and height ? .Is there a better solution ?

Comment: It largely depends on what you're trying to achieve. Provide an example and explain what is the desired behavior. I can't recommend anything without knowing what you need it for (i.e from UI perspective, I mean). Some solutions are good for some purposes, others for others.

Comment: Thanks. I have a canvas element that needs to be hidden within its parent. I have created a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q1h5aneL/ by wrapping a div around it and it works as i expect. If there is better way to hide the div without having wrapping di, please let me know.

Comment: @Tale, that's the proper way to trim content in HTML. You wrap it inside an element with set size(s) and overflow `hidden` (on one or both directions). There is no better way. If you want the parent element to allow scroll when necessary, you can set `overflow` to `auto`.